# Cordova contacts plugin does not include the device owner

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using the Cordova contacts plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts) in my app to fetch contacts from the address book on the device. Android allows a user to specify him- or herself:

[image]

On an Android 6.0 simulator, calling `navigator.contacts.find` **will never** respond with the user that was set up in the profile. On a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 4.4.2 it **will never** respond with the user in the profile either. An LG Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1 **will** respond with the profile. In all cases, "regular" contacts are always properly found, so it just seems to be the profile of the user that is failing.

How can I consistently fetch the profile of the user as well?

Answer (score 0):

After find try searching for me.E.g navigator.contacts.find('me');
Or better if you want to find info about the device why don't you the device plugin or sim plugin provided by cordova.

Comment: Hi Piyush, thanks for the fast response. Searching for `me` won't find the profile information either it seems. I am not interested in the device or SIM data however, I want to fetch the home address of the user for instance, and that can only be found in the address book.

Comment: No, I mean the physical address, as in "Fifth Avenue 5, New York". This seems to be a bug in the plugin: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11741.